# Данные в Offset ()

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, такой вопрос, в консольке в браузере, $('.dropdown').offset () работает корректно и выдает {top: 350, left: 828}. Вопрос такой, как можно взять только высоту и занести ее в переменную? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

то что возвращает offset() - просто объект. Поэтому просто берёте свойство объекта

```
var this_top = $('.dropdown').offset().top
```

не забудьте получаться положение в ready - что бы DOM сформировался